# Why should we use Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Firebase is undoubtedly the best backend system (at least according to me) when it comes to the smoothness of development. But as far as I have read in several articles, the stored data may be exposed if the security rules are not written properly. But Firebase projects are directly connected with our apps (using package name and SHA1 fingerprint, though optional) Now the question arises, if my Firebase project is bound with my app, why should I even care about security rules? How can my project be accessed from elsewhere?

Comment: This is a very broad question, but just, for instance, to not allow one user to access another user's data. These would be user-level security rules in the firestore. eg- 
`match /users/{userid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userid;
    }
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the longest time of its existence Firebase projects were actually **not** tied to your specific app, or at least not for the services where it supports security rules (Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage). So anyone with the configuration data could make calls to your project using the API, and security rules were the only way to protect the data from malicious users.

At I/O 2021, Firebase introduced [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), which for the first time adds an app-level check to three products: Realtime Database, Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage. App Check works with the attestation providers of each supported platform (such as SafetyNet on Android) to only accept requests that are coming from *your* app, and rejecting others.

While this provides a broad level of protection, it is still possible that a malicious user breaks the mechanism. So I will still implement security rules in **my** Firebase projects, and thus combine the broad protection that App Check offers, with fine-grained access control from within the security rules.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Puf. But if Firebase projects were **not** tied to our app, then what was the significance of registering with *package name* and sometimes even *SHA1 fingerprint*? Also, can the security rules be breached by anyone having the configuration data? For example, if we use **".write": "$uid == auth.uid"**, can anyone with all the cofiguration data still write into the database (who is not a user of my app)?

Comment: `".write": "$uid == auth.uid"` requires that `auth.uid` matches the `$uid` of that context, and `auth.uid` cannot be spoofed. But there's nothing keeping any user from creating an account outside of your app, so they can call the API however they want - not just with the code paths in your app.

Comment: *"But there's nothing keeping any user from creating an account outside of your app, so they can call the API however they want"*. - Does **creating** an account mean authenticate as a user?

Comment: I am a beginner, so correct me if I am wrong. 1) Firebase projects (RT database, Firestore) can be accessed by anyone if read-write permissions are true 2) Only the users of **my** app can be authenticated. So if I use **auth.uid** it means only the users of *my* app are allowed 3) The security rules cannot be breached or altered by anyone. 4) If I write the security rules correctly, the data cannot be accessed or manipulated by intruders. 5) Firebase App Check provides additional layer of security by ensuring (in most cases) that the requests come from **my** app.

Comment: But I have another doubt. If a user signs in with Google account, can the user with the same Google account read or write the data outside of my app? I am sorry if the question is a stupid one.

Comment: Sorry, but there are just too many questions here for me to answer efficiently in a comment. I'll try to answer what I can, but recommend that you search for anything I don't cover here, as many of these have been answered before, and posting specific, concrete follow-up questions for the others. 2) Anyone can call the Auth API to sign in - whether they use your application code or not. 5) correct, when you enable enforcement in App Check, only calls from your app are allowed to access the resources in the Database and Storage. Calls from other code are rejected.