# What is the most secured security rule to enable only a user of my app to change a value from false to true?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I integrated Firebase into my app.
The user details in my database are stored as **users** -> **uid** -> **key**: name, **value**: name of the user, **key**: dept, **value**: department of the user, **key**: done, **value**: false

Now if a user does a particular activity (or work) in his/her app, the value of the key **done** will be changed to *true*. I don't want any malicious user to create an account and change the value of the **done** key to true. What will be the most secured security rule in that case?

Comment: **".write": "$uid == auth.uid"** will work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to check if the current authenticated user's ID matches the document he/she tries to update. You can do it in Firebase security rules by adding this:

```
 match /users/{uid}/{documents=**} {
     allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
 }
```

***request.auth.uid*** is the uid of the user who sent request to Firebase and ***uid*** is the document id. This statement will return true only when the user modifies his/her document.

Comment: But as @FrankVanPuffelen mentions in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860417, anyone can call the Auth API and thus, anyone can get authenticated. So, there can be authenticated malicious users too. What was the way to restrict it before Firebase App Check?